# Firefox 7 refuses to download file returned by PHP

Tags: php, firefox, header, download

after upgrading to Firefox 7, I can't download files I output via PHP on my sites.

An example:

Let's say I have link http://example.com/download/1 returning pretty normal 800KB .ZIP file, with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .trim($filename). "");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " .filesize($filePath). ")"); 
readfile($filePath);
flush();
```

Every possible browser, even older versions of Firefox, start downloading the file as usually. Firefox 7 throws "Corrupted Content Error".

Does anyone notice similiar behaviour? Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a superfluous `)` in the `content-length` field. That may screw up the file size that the browser expects from the download, and cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an extra `)` in the `Content-Length` header

This:

```
header("Content-Length: " .filesize($filePath). ")");
```

should be

```
header("Content-Length: " .filesize($filePath). "");
```